# vert.x web error handler for more than one status code

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

I would like to customize the error response automatically thrown by vert.x web on various [scenarios](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_route_match_failures). For example, vert.x web will throw 404 for no router match and I would like to catch that and add some custom error message to the response. I found that it's possible to do that via [errorHandler](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/Router.html#errorHandler-int-io.vertx.core.Handler-) but the problem is it only handles one error code at a time.

```
Router.errorHandler(404) {
    // handle error for only 404 raised by vert.x
}
```

I would like to do something like below

```
Router.errorHandler(404, 405, 406 or any other) {
    // handle error raised by vert.x
}
```

Minimal code sample:

```
val router: Router = Router.router(vertx)

router.router(HttpMethod.GET, "/test").handler { ctx ->
    // handle the request GET for http://localhost/test
}

router.route().failureHandler { ctx ->
    //expected to get called for all failures for this router
}

router.errorHandler(404) { ctx ->
    // this 404 error comes from vert.x look here -> https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_route_match_failures
}
```

so now if I call,

GET on endpoint http://localhost/test --> calls my "/test" handler

GET on endpoint http://localhost/testksjgh  --> vert.x raise 404 error and captured by my errorHandler

POST on endpoint http://localhost/test --> vert.x raise 405 error but don't get captured by failure or errorHandler.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a general `failureHandler` to your `route`. There you can put any logic on depending on the http status code:

```java
Route route = router.get("/*");
route.failureHandler(ctx -> {
  int statusCode = ctx.statusCode();
  HttpServerResponse response = ctx.response();

  switch (statusCode){
    case 404, 405, 406:
      response.setStatusCode(statusCode).end("404, 405, 406 error handled");
    default:
      response.setStatusCode(statusCode).end("Different Error");
  }
});
```

Comment: I would be much happier if it's the case but I already tried this one "failureHandler" but It's not getting called for internal failures from vert.x. It's only get's for ctx.fail(404) if I manually fail some route

Comment: can you share how your routes are set up?